# Invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I know this error has been asked before but i couldn't understand other answers. This is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int processDate (int day){
 if (day <= 6){
     return day;
 }else{
   day -= 7;
   return processDate(day);
 }
}

int calculateYear (int year){
    return year;
}

int main(){
 int monthCode [] = {6,2,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,4};
 string dayName [] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Sunday"};
 int d,m,y = 0;
 int dayNum;
 cin >> d >> m >> y;
 dayNum = d + monthCode[m] + calculateYear[y];
 cout << dayName[processDate(dayNum)];
}
```

calculateYear() and processDate() are 2 functions empty at the time. I was just testing if the basic code compile. The error ocures on "dayNum=..." before the second "+". Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a syntax error at `calculateYear[m]`. Please post your actual code.  Also show us all relevant function definitions, we're not psychic.

Comment: Please post the full code, including your definitions for calculateYear and processDate.

Comment: i edited the quetion with my full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `calculateYear(y)` with parentheses not square brackets.

Comment: thank you... i missed that calculateYear() is a function not an array\

Answer (score 0):

The error says that somewhere there is an assignment to a int of a pointer to a function.  The pointed-to function returns an `int` and takes an `int` as a parameter.  Look for something like this:

```
int myfunc (int);

int x = myfunc;
```